# How to build central sign architecture with spring security and angularjs applications

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-security, single-sign-on

I have 4 single page applications with same technologies: Spring MVC, Spring Security, Angulajs.
Each application has own ldap authentication and authorization. We want to build a single sign architecture and make a central authentication application. And make the other 4 application use this central application.
When user login into one of the apps, he should not need to login the others.

What is the easy way to implent this in server side and client side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is Single Sign-On (SSO). There are two options:

- Use some existed SSO server like [CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas).
- Do it yourself using subdomain cookie technique.

First option is exactly what you want implement. When you open URL of app1 you will be redirected to SSO server and prompted for login/password. After successful authentication you will be redirected to app1 URL. Now if you open app2 URL you will be signed in automatically. One of advantages is that user password is stored only in SSO server.

Second option is more lightweight IMHO, because instead of using existed SSO server for sharing authentication information between your apps you use HTTP cookies. From the other side you need to write some minimal authentication code which may be less secure.

Subdomain cookie technique:

- Use subdomains for all your apps (app1.domain.com, app2.domain.com)
- When user connects to app1, generate some token (your session id), store it in some shared DB and as a cookie for domain.com
- When user opens app2, check if token is present (as a cookie for domain.com), verify that it is valid (use shared DB) and allow access.

It is very simple algorithm that do not take into account all possible security vulnerabilities (like [session fixation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation) for example). So if you do not have enough time to solve them it may be better to go with first option.

Comment: Thank you for answer. What would you offer for first option? CAS or something else?

Comment: I worked only with CAS. AFAIK it is a good option (free, open source, widely used, there is a support for apps secured with Spring Security). I recommend it. Authentication workflow is not simple, so you will need some time to be familiar with it. It makes sense to check other alternatives. Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173704/which-sso-framework-to-use. There is a link to nice presentation.

Comment: Forgot to mention that by default with CAS you must secure all your pages. If you have both secured and public pages it may be difficult to do with CAS.